# an LM13700 can be configured as a "floating" voltage controlled resistor ; How resistor-like is it?

Tags: resistors, components, ota

I want to use an [LM13700](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm13700.pdf) as a voltage controlled resistor, and I want it to act like a rheostat. When will it act non-linearly?

The description of this circuit is on page 15 of the datasheet, and the circuit diagram is on page 16, figure 28.

I intend to use two of them to produce a variable voltage divider for an audio signal. I am worried that the resistance might vary with regards to frequency, temperature etc.

Comment: Show a bit of research, doc, and post links to the datasheet so we don't all have to look for it. If you give some details on your application you might get some useful advice in the answers and  comments.

Comment: If you want answers to this question, it would be advised that since people volunteer their time here, that you make it as easy as possible for them.  For example embedding links to data sheets, even embedding pictures is advised (of course you must provide attribution) as some people won't follow links. Roughly speaking, the effort that others will put into an answer  will be proportional to the effort _you_ put into the question.

Comment: Please specify what it is your trying to control. The LM13700 is for controlling audio levels for VCO's, mixing boards, etc. It is not designed to control power. Use of the word "rheostat" implies the control of power. Please clarify these issues.

Comment: Edited the question to add details.

Comment: Why aren't you using the stereo volume control circuit of page 14, Figure 22? Again, "rheostat" is the wrong word for an audio application.

Comment: The voltage divider isn't between the output and ground. The application would be taking an input signal, and dividing it into two separate signals. The proportion of the $V_{pp}$ of each output should be controllable.

Comment: Not that simple. The input impedance is as low as 10K ohm, and the max drive current with +/- 15 Volt supplies is only 500uA. You need op-amps on the input and outputs. Also your using the wrong diagram. Your referring to audio panning from L to R, with the volume equal if the potentiometer is in the middle of its range, and it should be a slide type, so panning is easy.

Comment: Qty 2 of Figure 20 sharing the same audio input would be better. The dual linear pot varies from +14v to -14v. The slew rate is great - 50v/uS, but the THD is terrible, about .1%. This will be noticeable with SACD or high definition audio. Please review and re-think this project. It will be a lot of work with dubious benefits.

Comment: Note that Transconductance Amplifiers are relatively noisey devices. Not something you want to use in a precision instrument. They made cool guitar pedals back in the 80's but otherwise, they're nearly useless.